# How to send Apple Push Notifications from Windows machine?

Tags: ios, windows-7, apple-push-notifications

I have Mac machine and Windows machine. I want to use the Windows machine as a server to connect with APNS. It is possible to use the Windows machine as a server for APN? If it is possible, what do I need to setup for APNS connection? How I can keep/install `.pem` files and `.csr` files in Windows? Can anyone please help me on this? I have searched MAMP for Windows to use Apache server and MySQL server but MAMP only available for Mac machine. Is there any alternative for Windows 7?

Comment: Please do not use inline code formatting for things that are not actual code. It isn't used to emphasize phrases. You would use bold or italics for that instead.